# Can I carry more than two weapons at once?

Tags: duke-nukem-forever

I'm playing DNF...I know it isn't that good that it supposed to be, but I loved Duke Nukem 3D. My problem is that I can only have 2 weapons on me. What a nonsense. Duke can fire 5 weapons at the same time while kicking and moving.

So do you know any workaround here to be able to have more than 2 weapons?

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: The only thing solution I could think of would be if the game has an editable file that contains a constant along the lines of MAX_WEAPONS. I don't own the game though, so I'm unable to check. 

HAve you  tried looking for such a file?

Comment: I even tried Win32DAsm. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.joystiq.com/2011/07/29/upcoming-patch-to-expand-duke-nukem-forevers-weapon-limit/), after a recent PC patch you can now hold four weapons at once.

It's currently unknown when/if this patch will come to XBox 360 and PS3

Comment: This patch was released today (August 2nd, 2011) on Steam http://store.steampowered.com/news/5978/

Answer (score 2):

You can have four weapons - two guns, tripmines, pipebombs.

Since you're on the PC version, somebody might mod it at some point to let you have more than two guns. Maybe some of the trainers that are out could provide a workaround .